# Cassandra Replication With in cluster Without partitioning Data

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 nodes in cluster

```
     Node1 = 127.0.0.1:9160
     Node2 = 127.0.0.2:9161
     Node3 = 127.0.0.3:9162
```

I want to use only one node(node1) for insertion. Other two nodes should be used for fault tolerance on writing millions of records. i.e. when node1 is down either node2 or node3 should take care of writing.For that I formed a cluster with replication factor of 2 and added seed nodes properly in cassandra.yalm file. It is working fine. But due to partition whenever I write the data to the node 1, rows are getting scattered across all the node in the cluster. So is there any way to use the nodes for **only replication** in the cluster?...Or is there any way to **disable the partitioning**?...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Cassandra is a fully distributed system.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve here?  We have a 6 node cluster with RF=3 and since PlayOrm fixed the config bug they had in astyanax, even if we start getting one slow node, it automatically starts going to the other nodes to keep the system fast.  Why would you want to avoid great features like that????  IF your primary node gets slow you would be screwed in your situation.

If you describe your use-case better, we might be able to give you better ideas.